# How to reload data in initState() flutter while using pop

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two screens, the first one fetches the data from the database and shows it on the screen. And the second screen creates a new user/course and sends it to the database. But when I use a pop to go back to the first screen, I want to update its data. How can I do this?

How can I update the screen data when returning from the second screen?

First Screen:

```dart
 class CourseList extends StatefulWidget {
  const CourseList({super.key});

  @override
  State<CourseList> createState() => _CourseListState();
}

class _CourseListState extends State<CourseList> {
  Future<List<Course>?> listCourses = Future.value([]);
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      setState(() {
        var course = CoursesData();
        listCourses = course.getCourses();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = FutureBuilder(
        future: listCourses,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return createScreen(context, snapshot);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });

    return futureBuilder;
  }

 Widget createScreen(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushNamed('/courseForm', arguments: null);
                },
                child: const Text("Adicionar Curso"))
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            return CourseTile(snapshot.data[index]);
          }),
        ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Second screen:

```dart
IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final isValid = _fomr.currentState!.validate();

                Navigator.pop(context, true);
                
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.save))
```

EDITED:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var result = await Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushNamed('/courseForm', arguments: null);

                  if (result != null) {
                    setState(() {
                      var course = CoursesData();
                      listCourses = course.getCourses();
                    });
                  }
                  
                },
                child: const Text("Adicionar Curso"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you include the part that you navigate to second screen?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include how your _pushing_ the new screen?

Comment: of course, include in the code

Answer (score 3):

You can navigate to second screen like this:

```
var result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));

if(result != null && result){
   setState(() {
        var course = CoursesData();
        listCourses = course.getCourses();
   });
}
```

then in your second screen when you pop like this

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

as you are doing right now you pass back a `bool` variable to first screen which act like a flag and with that you can find when it is the time to reload the data. Also don forgot to `await` for the Navigator because of that you can receive the data from your second screen. Now when you come back from second screen, its going to update the ui.

Comment: I was gonna answer that. +1. But I think you should explain to the OP a bit more

Comment: I think it covered all the part, but if you think there is still something to say, fill free to update the answer, If it was not good enough I will edit that. @MendelG

Comment: No problem, I've decided to give my own answer quoting the documentation. But your answer is more practical, as it shows the OP _exactly_ what to do.

Comment: I tried to do what you told me, but it didn't work.  The variables that you said to create inside the button with setState still look for the old values. I updated my question showing what I did.

Comment: What I wanted to do, is when I finish the pop on screentwo reset my futurebuilder on screen one. Would there be a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `still look for the old values`? can you explain more? @LucasBarretoLuz

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) covers this example in detail. So I'll paste in the relevant part:

> ```
> Future<void> _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
>   // Navigator.push returns a Future that completes after calling
>   // Navigator.pop on the Selection Screen.
>   final result = await Navigator.push(
>     context,
>     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SelectionScreen()),
>   );
> ```

The key is in this line:

```dart
  final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SelectionScreen()),
  );
```

The result of `navigator.push` will be stored in `result`.

So in your case, you should do this after getting the result (as @eamirho3ein has answered first, so I'm explaining) :

```dart
 setState(() {
        var course = CoursesData();
        listCourses = course.getCourses();
   });
```

- Take a look at the Flutter example for [returning data](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)